# How can I output a message for a work macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can I display a message in a Word macro that says to wait a short time. The field should simply have the content "Please wait a short time" and the script should load in the background. (My script makes that with a serial letter each document is saved individually as PDF). The message should appear before it starts saving and close automatically when it is finished.

I have worked with the MsgBox before, but I read that it does not load the script in the background (only after closing the MsgBox)

```
Sub SerienbriefOneDoc()
'
' SerienbriefOneDoc Makro
'
'
 Dim Dateiname As String
 Dim LetzterRec As Long
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Visible = False

    'Variable declaration
    Dim sFolderName As String
    Dim sDesktopPath As String, sFolderPath As String

    'Find Desktop path location
    sDesktopPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\"

    'Define folder name to create on the desktop
    sFolderName = "Serienbrief"

    'Folder Path
    sFolderPath = sDesktopPath & sFolderName

    'Create FSO Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Check Specified Folder exists or not
    If oFSO.FolderExists(sFolderPath) Then
        'If folder is available on the desktop
        MsgBox "Der angegebene Ordner existiert bereits auf dem Desktop!", vbInformation, "VBAF1"
        GoTo PDFsave
    Else
        'Create Folder
        MkDir sFolderPath

        'Diplay messafe on the screen
        MsgBox "Ordner erstellt : " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & sFolderPath, vbInformation, "VBAF1"
    End If



PDFsave:

 'Const path As String = sFolderPath                                 'Speicherpfad des Resultates     N:\Lehre\Basislehrjahr\Auftraege\Projektarbeit\WordMakro\Serienbrief\save\
 ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdLastRecord
 LetzterRec = Word.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
 ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord

MsgBox "please wait a moment"

With ActiveDocument.MailMerge                                                                                               'Waehlt das aktuelle Dokument des Serienbriefs
         .DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord
         Do
             If .DataSource.ActiveRecord > 0 Then                                                                           'Prueft ob es mehrere Seiten fuer den Serienbrief gibt
                If .DataSource.DataFields("Name").Value <> "0" Then                                                         'zaehlt die Anzahl Datensaetz in der Spalte "Name"
                     .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                     .SuppressBlankLines = True
                        If Dir(sFolderPath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then                                                                'prueft ob es das Verzeichnis gibt.
                        Else
                            MsgBox "Verzeichnis existiert nicht"                                                            'Fehlermeldung falls das Verzeichniss nicht existiert
                        End If
                     With .DataSource
                         .FirstRecord = .ActiveRecord
                         .LastRecord = .ActiveRecord
                          dname = sFolderPath & "\" & .DataFields("Name").Value & "_" & .DataFields("Vorname").Value & ".pdf"            'erstellt eine Variable mit dem Pfad und dem Namen
                     End With
                        .Execute Pause:=False
                        ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=dname, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF                                     'benennt die Datei und aendert das Dateiformat auf PDF
                        ActiveDocument.Close False                                                                          'schliesst das Fenster
                 End If
               End If
             If .DataSource.ActiveRecord < LetzterRec Then                                                                  'prueft ob es noch eine Seite gibt im Serienbrief
                 .DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord                                                                    'nimmt die naechste Seite des Serienbriefes
             Else
                 Exit Do                                                                                                    'wenn es keine Seite im Serienbrief mehr gibt wird die Schleife beendet
             End If
         Loop
     End With
     Application.Visible = True
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True[enter image description here][1]
End Sub
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlznU.png
The picture shows how it should be (simply no MsgBox)

Comment: A msgbox requires a response, so i think you'll be best creating a form, opening and closing this around the code.

Comment: ... and show the form non-modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give a progress report on the status bar. For example:

At the top of your code, insert:

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, sBar As Boolean
SBar = Application.DisplayStatusBar
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
```

After:

```
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
```

insert:

```
j = .DataSource.RecordCount
```

After:

```
Do
```

insert:

```
i = i + 1
Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & Int(i / j * 100) & "%"
```

After:

```
Application.Visible = True
```

insert:

```
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = SBar
```

Answer (score 1):

Every function in the standard VBA library is synchronous: you invoke it, it does its thing, returns, execution resumes with the next statement.

There is no way to have a `MsgBox` show up and have any code running while it's being shown, because execution is waiting for the user to close the message box: the function won't return until it knows what to return, and thus your program can't resume until the return value for that `MsgBox` call is known - it doesn't matter that you end up discarding that return value.

I'd invite you to read [The Reusable Progress Indicator](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/01/12/progress-indicator/) (intermediate/advanced) for ideas involving a user form (forget `MsgBox` for this) - the simplest way to do this, is to have a non-modal user form running the show (the article demonstrates how to make a cancellable progress indicator that is modal and that does not run the show).